# Updating sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel on Input Change

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have the following problem:

I have created a JSONModel with data in my SAPUI5 application. After that I created an input field, which got as model the just mentioned JSONModel.
The value of the input field is bound to the model.

Now when I start the application, the initial value from the model is written to the input field. But if I now change the value in the input field, it will not be adjusted in the model. Only when I confirm the value in the field with Enter, it works.
Can I work around the fact that I have to press Enter after changing a value?

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.setDefaultBindingMode(sao.ui.model.BindingMode.TwoWay);
oModel.setData({
    test_value: "Hallo"
})

var oInput = new sap.m.Input({
    value: "{test_value}"
})
oInput.setModel(oModel);
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Set the property `valueLiveUpdate` on your `Input` to `true`.

Documentation can be found [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Input%23methods/setValueLiveUpdate)